# zf2 form disable select option(s)

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2

Is it possible to disable the options in a select element?

I have a form with a select element that by default has a lot of options available. During form creation, depending on information retrieved from the database, i would like to disable certain options.

Some research came up with 
`$form->get('selectElement')->setAttribute("disabled", array(0, 1, 2));` 
...which should disable the first 3 options, but unfortunately does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [disable some options select in Zend Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362010/disable-some-options-select-in-zend-framework-2)

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `setAttribute()` method to set the attributes of your `select` element, not its options. For this, you should use `setValueOptions()`:

```
$myOptions = $form->get('selectElement')->getValueOptions();
foreach ([0, 1, 2] as $value) {
    $myOptions [$value]['disabled'] = true ;
}
$form->get('selectElement')->setValueOptions($myOptions);
```

`$myOptions`must be an array of options:

```
[
    [
        'label' => 'My first option',
        'disabled' => false,
        'value' => 1
    ],
    [
        'label' => '2nd option',
        'disabled' => false,
        'value' => 2
    ],
    [
        'label' => '3rd option disabled',
        'disabled' => true,
        'value' => 3
    ],
]
```